# Which Third Rock From the Sun episode has the lobster claw?

Tags: episode-identification, third-rock-from-the-sun

I have seared into my memory a specific scene from *Third Rock From the Sun*, in which Harry reveals he is wearing a lobster claw-shaped oven mitt, and declares "Lobster claw!".

Details I'm less sure of:

I think Tommy is also in the scene, and it may be in a kitchen or the kitchen section of a shop. Harry probably then lunges at someone with the claw.

Does anyone know what episode that is in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the season 5 episode "[Rutherford Beauty](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0502708/?ref_=ttep_ep13)" (episode 13).

The scene is in a kitchen store where Sally is browsing and getting caught up in a video from the show's Martha Stewart expy (and ending up with a couple of books); Harry sees lobster-claw oven mitts and he and Tommy wander over for a look.  After the scene has followed Sally for a while Tommy reappears and gets chased by Harry wearing the oven mitts yelling "I'm a lobster!"

[image: He's a lobster!]

(Apologies for the poor image quality; I found a viewable copy of the video at dailymotion.)

Comment: Thank you! The actual "lobster claw!" moment is the pre-credits scene on the roof.

Comment: [I now have everything I need](https://tenor.com/tMup5m8d4EC.gif)